# Issue with DateTime.TryParse()

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have a string `"2/15/50"` that needs to be converted to datetime format and I am using the following code:

```
DateTime.TryParse("2/15/50", out dt);
```

The output I am getting is: `02/15/1950 12:00:00 AM`

The output expected is: `02/15/2050 12:00:00 AM`

Is there a way I can achieve the latter. Suggestions to use other functions are welcome. I tried using `Convert.ToDateTime` as well and it returns the same output as TryParse.

Comment: Are we back to Y2K?

Comment: add 100 years to result if date is smaller from whatever you feel limit value should be

Comment: whats the value of secName?

Comment: @Ben I have edited that part. It's a string which contains the date value, which I extract and convert to DateTime. The rest of the content in the string is irrelevant.

Comment: If the year is less than 10 years over the current year, it will give you the current (in this case century). Otherwise, it goes to the past. Year 29 will become 2029, but 30 will be 1930.

Comment: @insane_developer I have some values '8/15/30', '6/25/35' these get converted to 2030 and 2035 respectively. Selvin's adding 100 year was a solution I considered before posting this question but wanted to see if there was a better way to get this done rather than just adding years to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you,

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
ci.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099;
DateTime.TryParse("2/15/50", ci, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt)
```

Heres the documentation on the method, ParseExact allows you to specify the format etc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0

Here is where I got the culture information code
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-parse-string-dates-with-a-two-digit-year-and-split-on-the-right-century-in-c

Comment: If you give that method "15/02/50"  it still gives you `2/15/1950 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: I've updated my answer it should work for you now :)

Comment: Works now, but I think the `TryParse` vs `TryParseExact` is just muddying the issue. I think your `CultureInfo.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` should be the headline here.  Change your input to the same as the OP (including apparently en-US), and you'll get my +1

Comment: I would prefer to disambiguate the year from the input. There might be cases in which the correct year interpretation is not the one that was forced in the code.

Comment: Well, yes, it would be obviously better if the input had a 4-digit year, but assuming that the OP knows what the expected ranges of years is, and is going to get a 2-digit year, then I think this answer shows how to coerce it to be the 21st century rather than the 20th.

Comment: @insane_developer 4 digit dates are certainly a lot safer to work with.

Comment: @Danny Yes granted, cultureinfo is the real star here, I added the link to the blog i got it from for anyone that needs more information.

Comment: The user enters the string in either mm/dd/yy or mm/dd/yyyy and if it's the latter I don't need to go through much but it's the 2 digit that needs to me substring the value and convert and honestly I wasn't even considering the Y2K errors till I actually ran into it.

Comment: If you're going to stick to `TryParseExact` then I think you need your format to handle single digits, with "M/d/yy". TryParseExact won't work if you have the input "2/15/50" and "MM/dd/yy"

Comment: @Ben cases when the date is 8/6/28 the method doesn't parse. I am assuming this is because of the format used?

Comment: Updated to use datetime.Parse @AdarshRavi the code above should work now, changed it away from parseexact